# SQL Query: Need to speed up this query that diffs against two databases

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a query that works, but it's taking forever. It basically returns all the rows in table T (with a join condition) in database D not in table T2 (also with a join condition) in database D2:

```
select f.* from D.frames f
join D.items i on i.id=f.item_id
where f.item_id not in (
    select f2.item_id
    from D2.frames f2
    join D2.items i2 on i2.id=f2.item_id
    where i2.primary_type='xxx'
)
```

Any help with speeding up this query is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have i2.primary_type indexed?

Comment: post an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your-query-here]` please?

Comment: @Scotch I indexed primary_type as you said, query still runs slow.

Comment: is 'xxx' always a literal? Or is it a variable you haven't included here?

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems may be that the cross-database `NOT IN` isn't executing as a constant set.

Try `SELECT`ing from D2 into a temp table (so you have a fixed, in memory set) and then use that temp table for the `NOT IN` clause.

Better yet, you could `LEFT JOIN` the temp table in and check for a `NULL` on the field.

untested below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (item_id int); 
INSERT INTO 
    TempTable 
FROM 
    D2.frames f2
JOIN 
    D2.items i2 ON i2.id=f2.item_id
WHERE 
    i2.primary_type='xxx'; 

SELECT 
    f.* 
FROM 
    D.frames f
JOIN 
    D.items i ON i.id=f.item_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TempTable t ON t.item_id = f.item_id
WHERE
    t.item_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you use `where aField in (select...)` the subquery is evaluated once for every row in your table, so it is indeed a big penalty in performance.

I suggest you use a `left join`:

```
select 
    f.*
from 
    (D.frames as f
    inner join D.items as i on f.item_id = i.id)
    left join (
        select f2.item_id
        from D2.frames as f2
        inner join D2.items as i2 on f2.item_id = i2.id
        where i2.primary_type='xxx'
    ) as a on f.item_id = a.item_id
where a.item_id is null;
```

As an alternative, consider creating a temporary table and make this a two-step process:

```
-- Step 1. Create the temporary table with the ids you need
drop table if exist temp_myTable;
create temporary table temp_myTable
    select f2.item_id
    from D2.frames as f2
    inner join D2.items as i2 on f2.item_id = i2.id
    where i2.primary_type='xxx';
-- Step 2. Add the appropriate indexes
alter temporary table temp_myTable
    add primary key (item_id); -- Or add index idx_item_id(item_id)
-- Step 3. Run your query using the newly created temp table
select 
    f.*
from 
    (D.frames as f
    inner join D.items as i on f.item_id = i.id)
    left join temp_myTable as a on f.item_id = a.item_id
where a.item_id is null;
```

Hope this helps